# Python socket OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python

I am running this on a local host and keep getting `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` after closing the connection and trying to run it again.

```
    ### server ###
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()                           
    port= 9876                            
    serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  
    serversocket.listen(5)
    
    while True:
        clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
        print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
        msg = 'Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
        clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
        clientsocket.close()


    ### client ###
    import socket
    sock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()                           
    port = 9876
    
    sock.connect((host, port))                              
    msg = sock.recv(1024)                                     
    sock.close()
    print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the following statement before using the bind() method

> serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

If you still have problems, you can look at your network connections and close the one you used previously manually, for when you run the program again, if you have already put the above-mentioned instruction before the bind() method everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should close serversocket also

```
serversocket.close()
```